# Block Bootstrapped Sampling in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to implement Block Bootstrapping in Pandas.

For example, suppose my DataFrame looks something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'personid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'month': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'],
    'values': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900],
})

df
     month  personid value
0    Jan    1        100
1    Feb    1        200
2    Mar    1        300
3    Aug    2        400
4    Sep    2        500
5    Mar    3        600
6    Apr    3        700
7    May    3        800
8    Jun    3        900
```

In particular, the DataFame is unique at the `month`, `personid` and in reality contains many rows where each `personid` is associated with a different number of months.

I want to implement a "block bootstrap" at the `personid` level. That is, I want to sample with replacement from the set of all unique values in `personid` and then return a DataFrame from that sample carrying all the associated `month` and `value` columns with it.

So for example, I have something like this:

```
personids = df.personid.unique()
```

which in this case would result in

```
 array([1, 2, 3])
```

Then, I would sample with replacement:

```
np.random.choice(personids, size=personids.size, replace=True)
```

In this case, this might result in:

```
array([3, 3, 2])
```

So now, if that were the sampling that resulted, I would want a bootstrapped dataframe, call it `bootstrapped_df` such that `bootstrapped_df` would equal:

```
     month  personid value
0    Mar    3        600
1    Apr    3        700
2    May    3        800
3    Jun    3        900
4    Mar    3        600
5    Apr    3        700
6    May    3        800
7    Jun    3        900
8    Aug    2        400
9    Sep    2        500
```

The way I've done it so far is this:

```
def create_bootstrapped_df(df, sampled_personids):
    """
    Create "Block" Bootstrapped DataFrame given a vector of sampled_personids

    Keyword Args:
        df: DataFrame containing cost data at the personid, month level
        sampled_personids: A vector of personids that is already sampled with replacement.
    """
    bootstrapped = []
    for person in sampled_personids:
        person_df = df.loc[df.personid == person]
        bootstrapped.append(person_df)
    bootstrapped_sample = pd.concat(bootstrapped)
    bootstrapped_sample.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    return bootstrapped_sample
```

Basically what the function does is that it loops through the sampled personid vector and subsets the original Data Frame pulling out each of the personids. It then concats everything together. I'm afraid this is very inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does the link help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68462443/efficient-block-bootstrap-of-integer-sequences

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, I just figured out a very easy way to do this. If I set `personid` as the index, then I can subset the DataFrame by the index and it will do the thing I want.

For example, if I do:

```
sampled_personids = np.random.choice(personids, size=personids.size, replace=True)
```

that yields me

```
array([1, 2, 2])
```

And then if I do:

```
df.loc[sampled_personids]
```

I get:

```
          month personid value
personid
1         Jan   1        100
1         Feb   1        200
1         Mar   1        300
2         Aug   2        400
2         Sep   2        500
2         Aug   2        400
2         Sep   2        500
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `merge`. First create a `bootstrapped_df` with just the random `personids`:

```
bootstrapped_df = pd.DataFrame({'personid':np.random.choice( personids, size=personids.size, 
                                                             replace=True)})
```

for me, it was:

```
   personid
0         2
1         1
2         1
```

then use `merge` with the parameter `how='left'`:

```
bootstrapped_df = bootstrapped_df.merge(df,how='left')
```

and I get for `bootstrapped_df`:

```
   personid month  values
0         2   Aug     400
1         2   Sep     500
2         1   Jan     100
3         1   Feb     200
4         1   Mar     300
5         1   Jan     100
6         1   Feb     200
7         1   Mar     300
```

EDIT you can do everything in one line:

```
bootstrapped_df = (pd.DataFrame({'personid':np.random.choice( personids, size=personids.size, 
                                                             replace=True)})
                     .merge(df,how='left'))
```